Is what ChatGPT said true about the difference between "can" and "be able to"?
I asked ChatGpt this question:

A: We've got lost.
B: We should ask John for help. He grew up here, so he must know how to get to the train station. If we give him the information, he can give us directions/will be able to give us directions.
What's the difference between these two options

This is his response. Is what it said true?

In this context, the difference between "can give us directions" and "will be able to give us directions" is subtle but meaningful. Let's break it down:
"Can give us directions"
Implication: John already has the ability to give directions. The only requirement is providing him with the information he needs.
Meaning: If we give him the information, he has the existing ability to give us directions.
Example: "If we give him the information, he can give us directions."
This implies that John knows the area well and can provide directions as soon as we ask for them.
"Will be able to give us directions"
Implication: John's ability to give directions is contingent on receiving the necessary information. This phrasing suggests that his ability to help is future-oriented and depends on the condition being met.
Meaning: If we give him the information, he will then gain the ability to give us directions.
Example: "If we give him the information, he will be able to give us directions."
This suggests that John needs the information to be able to provide directions, focusing on the conditions that must be met for his ability to help to come into effect.
Key Distinction in the Example
"Can give us directions": Assumes John already knows how to help, and we just need to ask him.
"Will be able to give us directions": Emphasizes that John's ability to help depends on us providing the necessary information first.
Context Application
If John's ability is assumed to be ready and just needs activation:
"If we give him the information, he can give us directions."
If John's ability is seen as contingent on receiving the information:
"If we give him the information, he will be able to give us directions."
Both are correct, but the choice depends on whether you want to emphasize John's existing knowledge or the need to provide information for him to be able to help."


"If we give him the information" seems an unnatural thing to say in these circumstances. The only relevant things you could tell him are where you are and where you want to get to. The alleged 'difference' is so subtle as to be irrelevant.

The OP  has asked at least five questions about can/is able to.

If you have to come here to ask humans if what Chat GPT told you is correct then what is the point of it? In my experience, AI can be right sometimes, but it only takes a few supplemental questions to get it to completely contradict itself. It's not intelligence - it is simply a language model for a search engine. Learn to do your own research. You can come here to help make sense of your research, but not to fact-check a robot.

This question needs a more meaningful title, referring to the actual topic. Although it's clearly a duplicate - I hope the vague title wasn't selected because the OP knows it's a duplicate.

I don't understand your obsession with a perceived difference in this word choice. Why do you distrust all the advice you've already gotten here? This is starting to seem like unfriendly behavior.

Google books: he'll be able to

My downvote is not for ChatGPT it's for yet another question (18) focused on a pretty trivial point by the OP. Please find a real life situation that actually uses "will be able to", not a made up sentence that no one would ever say in real life.

The made up situation doesn't reflect real life. Are we in the 1980s before cell phones? Possibly, but then how would they contact John? Using a public phone booth? Maybe. In any case the dialogue should begin with, A: We're lost because that is their situation at the moment of speaking.  The group cannot be in the city, so let's pretend they are in a remote village and no one is around. If John lived in this village, he wouldn't need information because there can only be one station in the village.

Well, technically correct ... but most people don't use language that precisely.
Yes, technically, saying, "John will be able ..." could mean that his ability will exist at some time in the future, but does not necessarily exist now. Maybe he can't know but we expect him to gain additional information in the future.
But it is more probable that the speaker means that John will be able at the future time when we ask him. Not that he does not have the necessary information or skill now, but that we will not ask him to provide that information until a time in the future.
I'd be cautious about drawing conclusions from such subtleties in wording. Sometimes the speaker intends to make such a distinction, but often not. Unless they're a politician or a salesman. Then you might pay careful attention to exact words. Like if a reporter says, "Isn't it true that you took a $5 million bribe from XYZ Corporation?", and the politician replies, "Absolutely not! I never took a $5 million bribe from XYZ!", the statement may be completely true -- he really took a $6 million bribe.

Is ChatGpt’s comment about “can” also true?

I'd say the same "maybe, but probably not". It's the same issue of "will be able" being interpreted to mean is not able now, as opposed to, we are not asking him now.

I'd judge ChatGPT's answer as 'unhelpful'. It creates a grammatical stew out of a pretty simple question.
It is really just a question of present tense 'can' versus future tense 'will be able'. Obviously in many situations we have to use present tense to refer to things happening now, and future tense to describe things happening in the future.
However, in some contexts, 'tense' doesn't matter in English. This is particularly the case when dealing with hypothetical situations. Hypotheticals bring in subjunctive or irrealis moods, which have no placement in time, and which are formed in highly flexible ways.
So here, the use of 'if' puts us into a hypothetical situation, at which point you can pretty much choose whatever version of the verb 'to be able' you want.

If X, then he could ...


If X, then he can ...


If X, then he is able ...


If X, then he will be able ...


If X, then he would be able ...

Any of these would work, and they mean exactly the same thing, even though many people (and ChatGPT) will tie themselves in knots trying to claim there is a difference.

Well, people tell me this is wrong/ If I train hard, I can dance. They told me I should use “will be able to”

Hypothetical situation, but active verbs and active sentence, which needs to use the correct logical tense. But it seems you just want to be argumentative about this matter and refuse to listen to the responses you have already been given numerous times, so I'm not going to engage further in any debate.

Any nuanced difference between "can give us directions" and "will be able to give us directions" will be lost on many native speakers, and even for those speakers who would distinguish between them, the difference is hardly so marked that you should concern yourself about it.
he can give us directions:  he knows the area well enough to direct us
he will be able to give us directions: when we speak with him, he can give us directions (as he knows the area well )

But the OP doesn't want to hear that "can" and "able to" in this instance have practically the same meaning!

The OP has asked 18 questions about "able to" and "can"

What happened to the capital letter at the start of a new sentence, and the full stop (period) at the end? Tsk...tsk..

@Mari-LouA  They're pacifist bullet points.

It depends on context. If a person has a broken leg or brokem machine, they might not be able to physically. That is a major difference.

will be able to involves some futurity consideration.  It could be as simple as "when you see each other" when the verb is "advise" or it could involve something more complex, as I answered in one of those many questions, like "His job interview is later this week and after it takes place he will be able to advise you on the sorts of questions they ask."  Where his ability itself does not yet exist.


Can John give us directions to the park?
Yes, he can.

VERSUS:

Can John give us directions to the park?


I don't think he can, he doesn't know how to get there.




I don't think he will be able to because he has a toothache and can't talk right now.




and 2) mean the same thing except 2) implies a future, near future or the fact he has not yet been asked.




I don't think he can because he has a toothache and can't talk right now.




I think he will be able to tomorrow.



will be able to signals a situation where you haven't asked him yet. He will only be able to answer when you do. Or a physical capacity to do something.
(Please note: The entire discussion about giving him information doesn't work here because it is you who is asking for information, not him.)
